# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions when presenting modal view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, viewcontroller

I'm adding a help overlay view to my application, similar to Fandango's help view, and am getting an odd message in the console. The app doesn't crash but I think that my presenting a modal view when the my other view hasn't finished completely could be causing the problem.

The message I get in the console is:
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for .

Here is what I'm doing in my application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Defaults" ofType:@"plist"]]];

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"showHelpOverlay"]) {
        [self.viewController presentHelpOverlayViewController];
    }
}
```

Perhaps I should be calling my method in my main view controller in viewDidLoad or something?

Any ideas any one?

Comment: is your modal presentation animated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. thats right.

you could either do that, or

use nstimer to call presentHelpOverlayViewController with some delay

Comment: When I move that code into viewDidLoad, the overlay view does not appear. If I place the code, presenting the overlay, in viewDidAppear the overlay will show. The overlay does not show if present code placed in viewWillAppear.

Comment: it makes no sense for the OS to show another present a modal view, before its parentview has been shown. How does it behave if you set animated:NO/YES ?